# How I should modify Windows's files in order to load all the system in the RAM during the boot?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ramdisk

I would to make a partition in my SSD and put in it the Windows's installation files. So, I would modify that files in order to tell at the CPU to copy all the partition (with all the files of Windows 7 64 Bit) into the RAM and finally boot from it as an normal SSD drive. I would also that when I turn off my system all the changes that I have been done at the RAM booted copy of Windows should be saved to my partition into the SSD, thus when I reboot I can boot from my modified copy of Windows, and I keep my changes saved.

```
Booting process:

Read BIOS
Read the (say) x SSD's partition
Read Windows's files loaded in RAM

Shutdown process:

Copy Windows's files loaded in RAM
Paste Windows's files in the x partition on the SSD
Shutdown
```

PS

I have 16GB of RAM and I can update it to 32...

Maybe can this be helpful?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744530(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: If you don't use a uninterruptable power supply with such a system, the RAMDisk being the other part, you *ARE* going to lose data and perhaps corrupt your OS if a power failure happens.  If you do use a UPS they usually have a USB plug on them that will signal your computer to automatically shut-down in the case of power loss.

Comment: @Bill This idea is more likely a kind of test, I know that this is not the most secure system. However if a power failure happens I can lost what I have in RAM but my last updated copy of Windows into my partition on the SSD still survive. Thus, I'm going to lost only my last changes, if I don't update my copy of Windows into the SSD!